# Visual Studio 2022 unable to find FS minifilter driver project template

Tags: visual-studio, wdk, minifilter

My Visual Studio 2022 (Community Edition) doesn't list the template to create a FS minifilter driver project. I have tried to uninstall VS itself, all SDKs, all WDKs and re-installed following Microsoft recommendations here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#step-2-install-the-wdk

I can see a couple of drivers templates (including Filter Driver NDIS) but nothing regarding the FS minifilter.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Visual studio Community 2019 instead of 2022, installed the SDK + WDK and now it shows up.